# Is there any example of a vessel colliding with a cloaked object?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-eu

There are a surprising number of objects flying/floating around that can cloak. While I know space is, like, really big, I would have thought that cloaked objects, which have an innate advantage in areas that other ships would tend to congregate, would occasionally be involved in a collision with something. Are there any examples in Star Trek of a vessel colliding with another cloaked ship or other object? EU references are fine.

Comment: Oh, and just to get ahead of this example: I'm aware of the IKS Drovana being seriously damaged by a cloaked mine in the *Deep Space Nine* episode "Sons of Mogh". Unless someone can show that the Drovana actually *collided* with the mine and not merely triggered the mine to explode, that would not count. I also expect, from a canon perspective, for the answer to be "no", but I haven't watched every single episode and movie yet.

Comment: I would think this would not be a very likely scenario unless the cloaked ship wanted to collide with someone. The cloaked ship would undoubtedly keep a close eye on what is around it to keep that from happening... hitting someone while cloaked would defeat the purpose. That said, it would be funny to see two cloaked ships colliding with one another!

Comment: @Odin1806: I'm currently watching season 7 of DS9 and seeing Warbirds decloak pretty much right next to the station almost every episode. Considering the very real possibility that there could be cloaked Klingons also in the vicinity, I was pretty much imagining that very scenario.

Comment: in Enterprise, they appear to actually run into a couple of romulan mines, http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Romulan_mine  as one of them is stuck and damaged agaisnt the side of the ship, and hasnt exploded

Comment: @Himarm: That sounds like a good example.

Answer (score 11):

In Star Trek IV, a whaling ship in 1984 attempts to fire a harpoon and, to the shock of its crew, [their harpoon bounces off of a cloaked Klingon Bird of Prey (skip to 2:15)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RfLrqlpkh2A) captained by James T. Kirk, which then proceeds to decloak and chase the whalers away. In this case, it appears that Kirk *wants* to get in the way of the harpoon, essentially using the ship as a shield.

Comment: In one of the sequels, Klang's ship is hit by a single torpedo. It makes the cloaking go all blurry and visible.

Comment: @Valorum is blurry really visible though?!

Comment: @Odin1806 Visible enough

Answer (score 5):

Cloaking technology has been used to conceal minefields. During the 22nd century, the Romulans employed cloaked mines, one of which caused significant damage to the USS *Enterprise* (NX-01):

[image: chunk taken out of the nx-01]

We don't know for certain whether the mine actually collided or detonated with a proximity trigger; Reed describes it as "a thermo-kinetic explosion on the outer hull". Another mine however, definitely did collide with the ship, but failed to detonate:

[image: tucker and reed trying to remove the mine from the ship's hull]

In the 24th century, the Federation used cloaking technology on board the self-replicating minefield guarding the mouth of the Bajoran wormhole. I don't believe any ships ever triggered with these mines, however (and even in the event that they did, they were on proximity triggers, so it's unlikely that actual collisions would take place).

Answer (score 2):

There is a TNG episode, [*The Pegasus*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Pegasus_(episode)) (S07E12), that features a prototype ship, called herself [*Pegasus*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Pegasus), used to test various technologies.

One of such technologies was a [Phasing Cloaking Device](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Phasing_cloaking_device), that besides providing "standard" cloaking, also let the equipped ship to pass through normal matter.

Of course, not everything went well, the cloaking devices breaks and the little ship rematerializes inside an asteroid:

[image]

Comment: So, I phrased the question in an attempt to avoid the Pegasus being an answer. The asteroid wasn't cloaked for the Pegasus to run into, and the asteroid isn't a vessel since it's just a random floating rock so is disqualified from colliding with a cloaked object in the context of the question.

Comment: I'm sorry if my answer was not helpful to you, but it was not that clear that you didn't want to be answered with this Episode (maybe explicitly stating this would have been helpful); and, you wrote about "cloaked objects" colliding "with something", it wasn't clear to me what you exactly meant with "object" and "something", and that those terms didn't include ships.

Comment: Actually, in the reverse. I'm asking for any vessels that collided with another cloaked object. This answer would have made sense if the asteroid was a cloaked object, but I seriously doubt it was cloaked. I don't care if the vessel is cloaked or not, only if what they ran into was cloaked.

Comment: Yes, I understand this now, your first comment clarified everything, even if I still don't get how a ship is not an "object" or a "something"

Comment: A ship is an object. But I'm not asking if an object has run into a cloaked ship. Most objects, like asteroids, are not able to maneuver under their own power unless they have a propulsion system and have no way to intentionally change their direction. I'm asking if a ship has run into a cloaked object. The Pegasus, a ship, ran into an object that was never cloaked, an asteroid.

Comment: Perhaps something is being lost in translation? When saying "another cloaked ship or other object", the cloaked descriptor is being applied to both "ship" and "other object". I'm essentially saying "another cloaked or ship or other cloaked object", but repeating adjectives is... cumbersome.

Answer (score 2):

NX-01 Enterprise collides with the cloaking field of multiple Spheres, the first one unintentionally because they didn't know it was there.